# Sequelize Query : How to do parent and child fetch query when condition on 1 of the child is valid?

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a parent Table "Orders" and child table "Items". They have one to many relationships.  I need to do the query using the "Orders" table. I need the Items in the "include". I want to query the order which has a particular Item. But if it also has other items those too should get selected.

A toned-down version of my query looks something like this:

```
let term = 'phone';
Orders.findAll({
   include: [
        model: Item,
        where: {itemName: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` }}
    ]
})
```

The query happens but if an order has multiple items and if the item name doesn't have the 'term' in it then that particular item gets excluded. Only the item with the term is returned with the order record.

I want if the where condition is true for 1 of the items, all the other items should also get included.

For example, let's say I search for the term 'phone', I want to get the orders which looks something like the below:

Order No: 123ABC

Order Items:

1. Android Phone
2. Smart Watch

In my case, the smartwatch doesn't come with the "include" option.

I will be grateful if anyone can help me find a solution.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

If this sql can help you..

```sql
select *
from Order o 
inner join item i on i.orderId = o.id and i.itemName like %term%
inner join item i2 on i2.orderId = o.id
```

you can use sequelize like this!

```js
let term = 'phone';
Orders.findAll({
   include: [
        {
        model: Item,
        as : 'searchItem',
        attributes : [],
        where: {itemName: { [Op.like]: `%${term}%` }},
        {
        model: Item,
        }
    ]
})
```